# How to implement search function in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel and have some understanding problems how can I implement a search function to my app.

What I have tried so far.

I created a model that gets the data from the db (this is working)

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public static function scopeSearch($query, $searchTerm)
    {
        return $query->where('city', 'like', '%' .$searchTerm. '%')
                     ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' .$searchTerm. '%');
    }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
use App\Post;

    class PostsController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request) 
        {
            $searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');
            $posts = Post::all()
            ->search($searchTerm);
            return view('posts.index', compact('posts', 'searchTerm'));
        }

       public function show($id)
       {
           $post = Post::find($id);
           return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
       }
    }
```

With php artisan tinker the model is working. I'm getting the db query.

On the front-end I have a simple input field with a submit button:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <form action="posts.index" method="GET">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchTerm" placeholder="Search for..." value="{{ isset($searchTerm) ? $searchTerm : '' }}">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, now, how can I retrieve the data from the controller if I input something in the search input field? The code is only working when I get all the posts. I need to include somehow the `serachTerm` from the controller

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">{{ $post->Name1 }}</h3>
                <small>Created at: {{ $post->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}</small>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
$posts = Post::search($searchTerm)->get();
```

Comment: Just to expand on this when you do `Post::all()` it executes the query immediately so the search query scope doesn't get applied. So apply the scope like in the answer here then you have to call `get()` to actually execute the query and get the results.

Comment: Make sure to add larqavel/scout to your project and add the trait to the model before using search()

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to install `laravel scout`

Use: `composer require laravel/scout`

Next you need to publish the Scout configuration using the `vendor:publish` command. This command will publish the `scout.php` to your config directory.

Here is the command: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"`

Last step would be `Laravel\Scout\Searchable` trait to the model you would like to make searchable.

Then its simple for use as: `NameOfModel::search($searchText)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get all record and then applying your scope function, rather then get all records just try:

```
$searchTerm = $request->input('searchTerm');
$posts = Post::search($searchTerm);
return view('posts.index', compact('posts', 'searchTerm'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel makes it really easy to do searches, as well as custom searches like live results, and etc. Just make sure to throttle your HTTP requests on the front end.

```
/**
 * Get a breed by name (returns similar results)
 * @param $term
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function getBreedByName($term)
{
    // Find an Breed by name
    $matchedTerm = Breed::where('text', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get();
    return response()->json($matchedTerm);
}
```

Then create a reference to that controller and method in your routes. In my case, I used the following in /routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/breeds/search/{term}', 'BreedsController@getBreedByName');
```

I hope this is helpful! Let me know if you have any questions or if this didn't cover your question.