# How to optimize search functionality in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, search

I am facing a problem with my laravel app while using search functionality.
Here is my code for search function

```
use DB;
public function search(Request $request){  
        $query = $request->input('query');
        $products = DB::table('products')
                    ->where('product_title','like','%'.$query.'%')
                    ->get();
```

Lets imagine I have product title as "Demo Product" in my app. There is no problem if I intend to search product with keyword like de/d/mo/pro etc.Those keywords showing some result.
But how can I get search query result if I search with keyword like "deemoo"/"prooductt" etc [Intend to show "Demo Product"].Please give me some suggestion if you can.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Or laravel scout maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/51158143/5300921

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a full text search index in the database of your choice. You can read more on full text indexes for MySQL [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

To actually use the index with Laravels Eloquent you need to use a raw query.

```
User::whereRaw("MATCH(product_name)AGAINST('soccer' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

To make the syntax a bit nicer you can add a scope to your Product model.

```
public function scopeNameMatches($query, $searchTerm)
{
    return $query-> whereRaw("MATCH(product_name)AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $searchTerm);
}
```

And you would use it by calling the scope in the following way.

```
Product::nameMatches("soccer")->get();
```